# Htaccess rule to nginx

Tags: apache, .htaccess, nginx

i'm trying to rewrite the htaccess rule to nginx rule.
this rule is used to load a php page for robot (like google robot).

here my htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^localhost$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/faq/$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)_escaped_fragment_=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /files/snapshot_loader.php?snapshot_page=%1%2 [L]
```

can you help me ? i try this one, but redirect never work....

```
 location /faq {
        if ($query_string ~ "^(.*)test(.*)$"){
          RewriteRule  ^(.*)$ http://www.google.com permanent
        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

First, there is no `$query_string` variable in nginx. And the second thing is there is no `RewriteRule` directive in nginx.

In nginx, the query string is stored in `$args` and you want the `rewrite` directive:

Try something like:

```
location /faq {
  if ($http_host ~* "^localhost$") {
    if($args ~* "^(.*)_escaped_fragment_=(.*)$") {
      set $newargs $1$2
      set $args '';
      rewrite ^ /files/snapshot_loader.php?snapshot_page=$newargs
    }
  }
}
```